# "a" overwrites file instead of appending

Tags: file, csv, python-3.x, dictionary

I have tried every format this could be written in. Whenever Python reaches the line to append to `Scores.csv`, it overwrites the file instead.

There are no errors, it just won't append. I'm not sure if it's because I'm trying to write to a `.csv` file instead of `.txt`, but if it's because of that, there has to be a workaround.

Here is the faulty code:

```
#OPEN TEMP_SCORES FILE FOR READING
with open("temp_Scores.csv", "r") as scorefile:
    print("\nDEBUG: temp_Scores.csv is open.")
    reader = csv.DictReader(scorefile)
    for row in reader:
        print("\nDEBUG: Reading temp_Scores.csv..")
        with open("Scores.csv", "w") as scorefile:
            print("\nDEBUG: Scores.csv is open for writing...")
            fieldnames = ["Name", "Class", "Score 1", "Score 2", "Score 3"]
            writer = csv.DictWriter(scorefile, fieldnames=fieldnames)

            #This line writes the actual "header" or "titles"
            writer.writeheader()

            NameExists = False
            #LOGIC TO DETERMINE WHAT TO WRITE
            #if new user's name is the same as in the file;
            if row["Name"] == UserData["Name"]:
                NameExists = True
                print("\nDEBUG: Name was found in temp_Scores.csv. Overwriting line..")

                #if Score 1 doesn't exist;
                if len(row["Score 1"]) == 0:
                    #makes NEW SCORE 1 the user's score
                    row["Score 1"] = UserData["Score"]
                    #actually write new scores to file
                    writer.writerow({"Name": row["Name"], "Class": UserData["Class"], "Score 1": row["Score 1"], "Score 2": row["Score 2"], "Score 3": row["Score 3"]})

                #if Score 2 doesn't exist;
                elif len(row["Score 2"]) == 0:
                    #makes NEW SCORE 2 the user's score
                    row["Score 2"] = UserData["Score"]
                    #actually write new scores to file
                    writer.writerow({"Name": row["Name"], "Class": UserData["Class"], "Score 1": row["Score 1"], "Score 2": row["Score 2"], "Score 3": row["Score 3"]})

                #if Score 3 doesn't exist;
                elif len(row["Score 3"]) == 0:
                    #makes NEW SCORE 3 the user's score
                    row["Score 3"] = UserData["Score"]
                    #actually write new scores to file
                    writer.writerow({"Name": row["Name"], "Class": UserData["Class"], "Score 1": row["Score 1"], "Score 2": row["Score 2"], "Score 3": row["Score 3"]})

                #if all Scores exist already; (update scores)
                else:
                    #makes NEW SCORE 3 the user's current score
                    newScore3 = UserData["Score"]
                    #makes NEW SCORE 2 the user's OLD SCORE 3
                    newScore2 = row["Score 3"]
                    #makes NEW SCORE 1 the user's OLD SCORE 2
                    newScore1 = row["Score 2"]
                    #gets rid of OLD SCORE 1

                    #actually write new scores to file
                    writer.writerow({"Name": row["Name"], "Class": UserData["Class"], "Score 1": newScore1, "Score 2": newScore2, "Score 3": newScore3})

                print("\nDEBUG: Updated new user's line")

    #if new user's name DOESN'T exist in the file already;
    if NameExists == False:
        print("\nDEBUG: Name was not found in temp_Score.csv. Appending new line..")
        #saves new user's details into a NEW LINE in the ORIGINAL FILE
        with open("Scores.csv", "a") as scorefile:
            fieldnames = ["Name", "Class", "Score 1", "Score 2", "Score 3"]
            writer = csv.DictWriter(scorefile, fieldnames=fieldnames)

            writer.write({"Name": UserData["Name"], "Class": UserData["Class"], "Score 1": UserData["Score"], "Score 2": "", "Score 3": ""})

            print("\nDEBUG: Appended new line onto existing file")

#temp_Scores.csv is no longer needed, so we're getting rid of it
os.remove("temp_Scores.csv")
print("\nDEBUG: Deleted temp_Scores.csv.")
```

Thanks so much for any help in advance.

Comment: You sure the problem isn't the `with open("Scores.csv", "w") as scorefile` bit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done some hours of thinking and re-coding.

@jDo's answer below is right regarding the fact that this snippet is redefining "scorefile" multiple lines, which led to only a single line being written to the file.

I've rewritten the whole code in mind and came up with a working solution:

```
    NameExists = False
    linesToWrite = {}
    with open("Scores.csv", "r") as scorefile:
        reader = csv.DictReader(scorefile)
        for row in reader:
            if row["Name"] == UserData["Name"]:
                NameExists = True
                if len(row["Score 1"]) == 0:
                    newScore1 = UserData["Score"]
                    newScore2 = ""
                    newScore3 = ""
                    print("\nDEBUG: Writing Score 1: " + newScore1 + " to line " + str(reader.line_num))
                elif len(row["Score 2"]) == 0:
                    newScore1 = row["Score 1"]
                    newScore2 = UserData["Score"]
                    newScore3 = ""
                    print("\nDEBUG: Writing Score 1: " + newScore1 + ", Score 2: " + newScore2 + " to line " + str(reader.line_num))
                elif len(row["Score 3"]) == 0:
                    newScore1 = row["Score 1"]
                    newScore2 = row["Score 2"]
                    newScore3 = UserData["Score"]
                    print("\nDEBUG: Writing Score 1: " + newScore1 + ", Score 2: " + newScore2 + ", Score 3: " + newScore3 + " to line " + str(reader.line_num))
                else:
                    newScore1 = row["Score 2"]
                    newScore2 = row["Score 3"]
                    newScore3 = UserData["Score"]
                    print("\nDEBUG: Writing Score 1: " + newScore1 + ", Score 2: " + newScore2 + ", Score 3: " + newScore3 + " to line " + str(reader.line_num))
                linesToWrite[reader.line_num] = {"Name": row["Name"], "Class": UserData["Class"], "Score 1": newScore1, "Score 2": newScore2, "Score 3": newScore3}
            else:
                linesToWrite[reader.line_num] = {"Name": row["Name"], "Class": row["Class"], "Score 1": row["Score 1"], "Score 2": row["Score 2"], "Score 3": row["Score 3"]}
    with open("Scores.csv", "w") as scorefile:
        fieldnames = ["Name", "Class", "Score 1", "Score 2", "Score 3"]
        writer = csv.DictWriter(scorefile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
        writer.writeheader()
        for key, line in linesToWrite.items():
            writer.writerow(line)
    if not NameExists:
        linesToWrite = {"Name": UserData["Name"], "Class": UserData["Class"], "Score 1": UserData["Score"], "Score 2": "", "Score 3": ""}
        with open("Scores.csv", "a") as scorefile:
            fieldnames = ["Name", "Class", "Score 1", "Score 2", "Score 3"]
            writer = csv.DictWriter(scorefile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
            writer.writerow(linesToWrite)
```

Thanks for anyone who distributed a thought or possible solution.

Answer (score 1):

You're redefining "scorefile" multiple times in a nested loop. Try giving each open file a new handle name ("scorefile1", "scorefile2", "scorefile3" or whatever) to eliminate the ambiguity.

Also, I don't see any definition of "NameExists" outside the loops - is it defined before the code you pasted here?

Comment: I'm not writing to multiple files, only one.

Comment: Also, yes, NameExists is defined before my snippet.

Comment: @Medallyonify You're right. You were only writing to one file but you were OPENING multiple files under the same handle. Un-nesting your "with open"s probably fixed it because it means that only one file is open at a time now (I don't think the change to a single csv-file, Scores.csv, makes a difference). Anyway, glad you solved it :)